# Did Nero's ship go to another timeline?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009

We know that red matter caused a [singularity that opened a black hole](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Red_matter) pulling Spock Prime and Nero into an alternate time.

Near the end, when Spock crashes the ship into the Narada, [it opens up another singularity](https://youtu.be/zlGRNRAL148?t=203), and the Narada gets pulled in and destroyed. Is there any official source that states where it went? Another timeline? Nothingness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per the film's [official novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_(novel)), Nero's ship, The Narada was destroyed **utterly**, torn apart into fundamental particles, then fed directly into the maw of a black hole and crushed into the singularity at the centre.

> The main bridge screen offered a final glimpse of the Romulan commander they had known as Nero: defiant, half-mad, and ultimately frustrated as he joined his ship in being crushed down into his subatomic components.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek - Novelisation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek_(novel))</sup></sub>

Note that Nero was unable to use the singularity to enter a different timeline

> **In the absence of full warp power there is no possible way you can attempt to escape by utilizing the anomaly to attempt a time shift** — you have no maneuverability. None of you will survive without assistance — which we are willing to provide.”